# Beta version Owl Carousel, help for a total beginner

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I want to use that super carousel but i don't get why it looks like this. 
[Before grabbing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpOxr.jpg)

[image: Tadam]

& Then. Just made that :

(function($){

```
  $('.carousel').owlCarousel({
      items: 1,


  });
})(jQuery);
```

Could anyone point the problem ? Is my stylesheet interfering with it? 
Trying to learn and just begun. 
Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Where is your code being called from ... in `<head>` or end of `<body>`

Comment: Yeah, get some errors for cursor,user-select and -moz-transition. My code is being called at the end of <body>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely bizarre, but try changing your class name to `owl-carousel` in your HTML.

Try the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({"items": 1});
});
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvnzgwzo/4/).

According to the [documentation](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/started-installation.html), this class name may be mandatory - whether implied for only the optional default styling or not I am not sure.

> You don't need any special markup. All you need is to wrap your
>   divs(owl works with any type element a/img/span..) inside the
>   container element `<div class="owl-carousel">`. Class "`owl-carousel`"
>   is mandatory to apply proper styles that come from `owl.carousel.css`
>   file.

Comment: Note that the wrapping IIFE is not the same as `$(function(){})` which is equivalent of `$(document).ready()`. Fiddle is wrapping all this in `onload` handler

Comment: Ah yes, I do need some reminders about that from time to time, but I was aware of the difference - simply following the same js provided.

Comment: Might be that plugin not even being initialized if code is in head

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. I whipped up a fiddle to test and was surprised to come across the same issue as the OP. I've used owl quite a few times, and with beta 2 - and I don't recall being locked into what the class name should be. Couldn't see any reference to it in the source either.

Comment: So now it looks like this : $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    
  });
});

Comment: and that's working outside the wrapper, but inside my wrapper (where i want it to be) the images don't display.

Comment: Problem solved, i checked it again and i was missing the row and the col. Thanks guys.